# react-native-ble-manager return device name null

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm using `react-native-ble-manager` for scan and show all devices. It's working fine, but it's not showing the name of devices (just the MAC id). Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    TouchableHighlight,
    NativeAppEventEmitter,
    NativeEventEmitter,
    NativeModules,
    Platform,
    PermissionsAndroid,
    ScrollView,
    AppState,
    FlatList,
    Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';
import BleManager from 'react-native-ble-manager';
import { stringToBytes } from 'convert-string';

const window = Dimensions.get('window');

const BleManagerModule = NativeModules.BleManager;
const bleManagerEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(BleManagerModule);


export default class App extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            scanning:false,
            peripherals: new Map(),
            appState: ''
        };

        this.handleDiscoverPeripheral = this.handleDiscoverPeripheral.bind(this);
        this.handleStopScan = this.handleStopScan.bind(this);
        this.handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic = this.handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic.bind(this);
        this.handleDisconnectedPeripheral = this.handleDisconnectedPeripheral.bind(this);
        this.handleAppStateChange = this.handleAppStateChange.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);

        BleManager.start({showAlert: false});

        this.handlerDiscover = bleManagerEmitter.addListener('BleManagerDiscoverPeripheral', this.handleDiscoverPeripheral );
        this.handlerStop = bleManagerEmitter.addListener('BleManagerStopScan', this.handleStopScan );
        this.handlerDisconnect = bleManagerEmitter.addListener('BleManagerDisconnectPeripheral', this.handleDisconnectedPeripheral );
        this.handlerUpdate = bleManagerEmitter.addListener('BleManagerDidUpdateValueForCharacteristic', this.handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic );



        if (Platform.OS === 'android' && Platform.Version >= 23) {
            PermissionsAndroid.check(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION).then((result) => {
                if (result) {
                    console.log("Permission is OK");
                } else {
                    PermissionsAndroid.requestPermission(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION).then((result) => {
                        if (result) {
                            console.log("User accept");
                        } else {
                            console.log("User refuse");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }

    }

    handleAppStateChange(nextAppState) {
        if (this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {
            console.log('App has come to the foreground!');
            BleManager.getConnectedPeripherals([]).then((peripheralsArray) => {
                console.log('Connected peripherals: ' + peripheralsArray.length);
            });
        }
        this.setState({appState: nextAppState});
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.handlerDiscover.remove();
        this.handlerStop.remove();
        this.handlerDisconnect.remove();
        this.handlerUpdate.remove();
    }

    handleDisconnectedPeripheral(data) {
        let peripherals = this.state.peripherals;
        let peripheral = peripherals.get(data.peripheral);
        if (peripheral) {
            peripheral.connected = false;
            peripherals.set(peripheral.id, peripheral);
            this.setState({peripherals});
        }
        console.log('Disconnected from ' + data.peripheral);
    }

    handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic(data) {
        console.log('Received data from ' + data.peripheral + ' characteristic ' + data.characteristic, data.value);
    }

    handleStopScan() {
        console.log('Scan is stopped');
        this.setState({ scanning: false });
    }

    startScan() {
        if (!this.state.scanning) {
            //this.setState({peripherals: new Map()});
            BleManager.scan([], 3, true).then((results) => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
                console.log('Scanning...');
                this.setState({scanning:true});
            });
        }
    }

    retrieveConnected(){
        BleManager.getConnectedPeripherals([]).then((results) => {
            if (results.length === 0) {
                console.log('No connected peripherals')
            }
            console.log(results);
            var peripherals = this.state.peripherals;
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var peripheral = results[i];
                peripheral.connected = true;
                peripherals.set(peripheral.id, peripheral);
                this.setState({ peripherals });
            }
        });
    }

    handleDiscoverPeripheral(peripheral){
        var peripherals = this.state.peripherals;
        console.log('Got ble peripheral', JSON.stringify(peripheral));
        console.log('NAME: ' + peripheral.name);
        if (peripheral.name === null) {
            peripheral.name = 'NO NAME';
        }
        peripherals.set(peripheral.id, peripheral);
        this.setState({ peripherals });
    }

    renderItem(item) {
        const color = item.connected ? 'green' : '#fff';
        return (
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.sendData(item.id, 'ola') }>
                <View style={[styles.row, {backgroundColor: color}]}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 12, textAlign: 'center', color: '#333333', padding: 10}}>{item.name}</Text>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 10, textAlign: 'center', color: '#333333', padding: 2}}>RSSI: {item.rssi}</Text>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 8, textAlign: 'center', color: '#333333', padding: 2, paddingBottom: 20}}>{item.id}</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        );
    }

    render() {
        const list = Array.from(this.state.peripherals.values());

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TouchableHighlight style={{marginTop: 40,margin: 20, padding:20, backgroundColor:'#ccc'}} onPress={() => this.startScan() }>
                    <Text>Scan Bluetooth ({this.state.scanning ? 'on' : 'off'})</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
                <TouchableHighlight style={{marginTop: 0,margin: 20, padding:20, backgroundColor:'#ccc'}} onPress={() => this.retrieveConnected() }>
                    <Text>Retrieve connected peripherals</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
                <ScrollView style={styles.scroll}>
                    {(list.length === 0) &&
                    <View style={{flex:1, margin: 20}}>
                        <Text style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>No peripherals</Text>
                    </View>
                    }
                    <FlatList
                        data={list}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderItem(item) }
                        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                    />

                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: have you resolved this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not.